# How to add left and right margins on a simple Alert dialog in android? (lets say 15 percent of the screen width on both sides)

Tags: android, webview, margin, android-alertdialog

I want to add left and right margin to android alert dialog on both sides lets say 15 percent of the screen width, this is my code so far, how may i do it?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

WebView wv = new WebView(context);
wv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
wv.loadUrl(ANY_URL_STRING);

alert.setView(wv);
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
alert.show();
```

Comment: create a custom dialog and in XML add what you want

Answer (score 0):

Creat a custom layout for your aleart dialog and give margin in xml.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(class.this);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        class.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final WebView wv= (WebView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

                // create alert dialog
                alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```